# Flexbox change responsive order

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This image shows the grid on desktop version:
[image]

And this image shows the same grid on mobile devices:

[image]

Requirements:

- On desktop, A height is equal to sum B/C and D
- On desktop, D width is equal to sum B and C
- On mobile I should get the order: D, A, B, C

I've tried this grid duplicating the HTML of D but in my project it is not acceptable to duplicate it and show/hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be done with flex? It would be easy using grid instead.

Comment: Well, not necessarily. I wrote the flexbox tag because that's what I was trying. What have you thought?